# Receiving an AJAX error when trying to add a block in Drupal 8

Tags: ajax, drupal, drupal-8

I did a clean install of Drupal 8.6.1. I neither installed any theme or module nor did I place any information or altered the configuration. I simply uploaded and installed/configured Drupal via the browser without any warnings or failures.

But when I try to add a block by clicking on the "Place block" Button within "Structure"/"Block layout" nothing happens. Safari/Chrome console prints this ajax error: "The response failed verification so will not be processed."

I installed Drupal on three different webspaces by now - same result. I tried Chrome, Safari and Firefox - same result. I even downloaded again the whole package from drupal.org and reinstalled it - same result.

Has someone experienced (and solved) the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

To hell! I've been dealing with this problem for hours now and I'm almost desperate... and now I realize that the firewall was the problem (we're behind a WatchGuard Firewall at work).

Unfortunately, I don't know exactly how to solve it, but everything works fine outside our network.